# Difference between Kali Linux and Santoku Linux

Tags: mobile, kali-linux

I would like to know, before I will install Santoku, what are the differences between Kali Linux and Santoku Linux? I know that Santoku is dedicated to mobile security testing, but Kali has some tools for mobile.

I focus on comparing tools for mobile applicatation testing, which system seems to be better?

Answer (score 1):

They both are similar in nature, just a Linux distribution with a bunch of tools pre-installed, you could take a vanilla Mint and install the software you need, so if you're debating which one to use you need to know what you will use it for, it comes down to the programs that you need and are comfortable using.

In my opinion, Kali is more complete, it comes with a much wider array of software, this also means its bloated, and at the end of the day I only use maybe 5 or 6 programs at most so having it installed is -for me- just the convenience of isolation inside a virtual machine with anything I *could* need.

Having said that, I do not think Kali linux comes with development tools.